# I'm lost in this "thought bubble" of a manga, I don't know what it says

Tags: translation, manga

In a manga, one person gets drunk and pushes another person down and the person being pushed thinks of this

[image: text image]

"酔ってるといえ何かおかしい..."
I think it says "there is something wrong for you to be drunk"
then he says "こうなたらこれ以上おかしい" and I think he says "this has turned into a weird situation" then he thinks "行動する前に従ってお方くがいいのか..."
and I think it says "Do you not think before acting?"

There aren't any translation for this manga yet but I'm trying to figure it out using google, I figured the previous pages but not this one and it'd be great if someone knows this, Thankyou.

Comment: You have some typo, and perhaps some spacing might help: "こうな**っ**たら、これ以上おかしい行動する前に、従ってお**く方**がいいのか..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

酔ってるといえ何かおかしい This is something along the lines of "He/She/They're being weird despite being drunk"

こうなたらこれ以上おかしい and 行動する前に従ってお方くがいいのか is actually one sentence not two separate sentences.

こうなたらこれ以上おかしい行動する前に従ってお方くがいいのか "Since they're acting strange maybe I should just follow along/play along before they do anything weirder"

Thats my take anyway. A bit hard without more context.

Comment: It makes sense now, thankyou very much!!!